# Ajax succes: function() : ' ' i declared but its value is never read

Tags: html, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to make the reaction likes of Facebook (at the moment just with words). 
So I'm at the part at Ajax and my succes doesn't want to succeed and my function() gives: *' ' i declared but its value is never read.* If i check another document with the same setup and everything it still continues and it succeed, so I don't know what i wrong with it or where the problem at the moment is.

My php code (buddyChat.php)

```
<?php
session_start();
if (empty($_SESSION['user_id'])) {
    header('Location: login.php');
}
//Hier mag enkel het gesprek te zien zijn tussen 2 users die met elkaar bevriend zijn
//tabel buddies >buddyID1 & buddyID2

include_once(__DIR__."/inc/header.inc.php");
include_once(__DIR__."/classes/Message.php");
include_once(__DIR__."/classes/User.php");

$userArray = $_SESSION['user_id'];
$userID = implode(" ", $userArray);
$currentUser = $userID;

//var_dump($_POST);

//$recipientID = implode(" ",$_POST);//om het getal terug te krijgen van de recipientID
$recipientID = $_POST['recipientID'];

//msg wordt in databank gestopt
if(!empty($_POST['message'])){
    $msg = new Message();
    $msg->setUserID($currentUser);
    $msg->setRecipientID($recipientID);
    $msg->setMessage(htmlspecialchars($_POST['message']));
    $msg->writeMessage();
}

//msg wordt afgedrukt/gereturned
$messages = Message::messagePrint($currentUser,$recipientID);
$names = User::printRecipientName($recipientID);


?><!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reaction.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/reaction.js"></script>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Je chat nu met <?php echo $recipientID ?></h1>
    <div class="">
        <div class="">
            <?php foreach($messages as $message): ?>
                <div class="singlechat">
                    <?php if ($currentUser == $message['senderID']): ?>
                        <div class="chat senderchat">          
                            <p><?php echo "Jij: " . $message["content"]; ?></p>

                            <span class="emoji_liked_png"></span>
                            <span class="emoji_liked_text">Emoji</span><!-- dit is de plaats waar je emoji komt te staan na het klikken-->
                            <ul class="reactions"><!-- lijst van alle emoji's-->
                                <li class="emoji" id="emoji-like" data-emoji="like"><a href="#" data-msgID="<?php echo $message['msgID'];?>">like</a></li> 
                                <li class="emoji" id="emoji-love" data-emoji="love"><a href="#" data-msgID="<?php echo $message['msgID'];?>">love</a></li> 
                                <li class="emoji" id="emoji-haha" data-emoji="haha"><a href="#" data-msgID="<?php echo $message['msgID'];?>">haha</a></li> 
                                <li class="emoji" id="emoji-wow" data-emoji="wow"><a href="#" data-msgID="<?php echo $message['msgID'];?>">wow</a></li> 
                                <li class="emoji" id="emoji-sad" data-emoji="sad"><a href="#" data-msgID="<?php echo $message['msgID'];?>">sad</a></li> 
                                <li class="emoji" id="emoji-angry" data-emoji="angry"><a href="#" data-msgID="<?php echo $message['msgID'];?>">angry</a></li> 
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                </div>
                <?php elseif ($currentUser == $message['recipientID']): ?>
                    <div class="">
                        <div class="chat recipientchat">
                            <p><?php echo $message["senderID"] . ": " . $message["content"]; ?></p>

                            <span class="emoji_liked_png"></span>
                            <span class="emoji_liked_text">Emoji</span>
                            <ul class="reactions">
                                <li class="emoji" id="emoji-like" data-emoji="1"><a href="#" data-msgID="<?php echo $message['msgID'];?>">like</a></li> 
                                <li class="emoji" id="emoji-love" data-emoji="2"><a href="#" data-msgID="<?php echo $message['msgID'];?>">love</a></li> 
                                <li class="emoji" id="emoji-haha" data-emoji="3"><a href="#" data-msgID="<?php echo $message['msgID'];?>">haha</a></li> 
                                <li class="emoji" id="emoji-wow" data-emoji="4"><a href="#" data-msgID="<?php echo $message['msgID'];?>">wow</a></li> 
                                <li class="emoji" id="emoji-sad" data-emoji="5"><a href="#" data-msgID="<?php echo $message['msgID'];?>">sad</a></li> 
                                <li class="emoji" id="emoji-angry" data-emoji="6"><a href="#" data-msgID="<?php echo $message['msgID'];?>">angry</a></li> 
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                <?php endif; ?>
            <?php endforeach;?>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div>
        <form action="" method="post">
            <input type="text" name="message">
            <input type="hidden" name="senderID" id="" value="<?php echo $currentUser?>">
            <input type="hidden" name="recipientID" id="" value="<?php echo $recipientID?>">
            <div class="">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btnChat" style="width: 90px">Send</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>


</body>
```

and my JS page (reaction.js):

```
$(document).ready(function (){

    $(".emoji").on("click", function() {
        // de variabelen om te zien welke emoji je hebt en op welke post je zit
        var emoji = $(this).attr("data-emoji");
        //var msgID = $(this).attr("data-msgID");
        console.log("here it works: " + emoji);
        //ajax sturen voor het in de database te stoppen
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: 'json',
            url: "ajax/Reaction.php",
            data: "emoji=" + emoji,
            succes: function (data){
                console.log("succes");

                $(".emoji_liked_text").html(emoji.toLowerCase()).removeClass().addClass('emoji_liked_text_'+emoji.toLowerCase()).addClass('active');
                $(".emoji_liked_png").removeClass().addClass('emoji_liked_png').addClass('emoji_liked_' + data_reaction.toLowerCase());$(".reaction-btn-text").text(data_reaction).removeClass().addClass('reaction-btn-text').addClass('reaction-btn-text-' + data_reaction.toLowerCase()).addClass("active");

            },
            error: function(data){
                console.log("didn't work");
            }
        })
        console.log("this shows up after Ajax");

    });


});
```

I used 3 console logs: 1 before ajax, 1 inside ajax and 1 after just to check everything what and when happens or that it even happens.
They go as followed. 1: the 1 before ajax. 2: the 1 after ajax. 3: the 1 in ajax. 
So atleast i get 3 console logs. But if I don't use the "*dataType: 'json*'" it doesn't even show the ajax console logs. Even in the other projext it doesn't write the "*dataType*" and it still works so I don't really know what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you really have to check how you write words.
i wrote success as succes. what was wrong and that's why it didnd't want to continue..

What have we learned? Check how you write everything! but it's always nice to have second eyes on them to see those mistakes